# Excel embed content of Worksheet2 into worksheet1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got a workbook with two sheets in.

Sheet 1 is a summary or overview, sheet 2 contains details that I would like to show in sheet1. Sheet 2 is going to be constantly updated and I want the view of it on Sheet 1 to be dynamic so we don't have to make the changes in both locations.

Am I able to dynamically link the content of Sheet 2 into Sheet 1.

The data I wish to display isn't typical Excel data, it is a diagram of a physical network switches & patch panels so I am hoping that I can just choose A1 to BF33 and display it, calling values from each cell isn't going to work.

I think I can do it if I keep everything in separate files (by insert > object > from a file) but I'd prefer to avoid splitting this into 2 files.

note that the above is a simplification of what I'm doing. My reason for not having 2 files is that my real world use case will involve lots of separate bits of data an I don't want one file for each bit of data.

EDIT : More detail

Contents of worksheet two:

I'm using this to map the physical connections in our network cabinets, one for each floor.
[image]

Here is a mock up of what I would like to see. Currently the area in the black box is just a copy/paste of the first image. I'd like it to dynamically update when changes are made to worksheet2. As you can see there are lots of empty elements and formatting that won't come through if I just link values.

If I were to do this in a web page I'd use something like an iFrame, if that helps anyones understanding.

[image]

Comment: It's a bit difficult to imagine what you're trying to do. "diagram of a physical network switches & patch panels" - are those pictures? I'm afraid we can't really help you without some sample data. " calling values from each cell isn't going to work" - what's exactly  the issue with that? ...

Comment: added more  detail, I can see why it didn't make sense initially. Hopefully this makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: At least partly addressing your question.: there is no way in Excel to transfer formatting automatically without vba.